# Pegar os valor que foram alterado no banco e parear com os novos valores

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estou com a seguinte questão. Ao fazer alteração em um determinado cadastro, preciso manter as informações antigas em algum lugar, primeiramente pensei em um esquema de log, mas chegou a hora de pegar os valores antigos, não consegui identificar quais foram os valores que foram alterados. Qual seria uma forma de fazer o seguinte:

```
TELEFONE_ANTIGO -> NOVO_TELEFONE
EMAIL_ANTIGO -> NOVO_EMAIL
```

Apenas quando o valor for alterado. Trabalhando com PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, acredito que a melhor forma de fazer isso é pelo próprio BD utilizando triggers.
Por exemplo, vamos supor que você a tabela contato abaixo:

```
|   CONTATO  |  
| id_contato |  
|  telefone  |  
|   email    |
```

Então você precisa criar uma outra tabela igual a `CONTATO` para guardar o histórico:

```
|   CONTATO_HIST  |  
| id_contato_HIST |
| id_contato      |  
| telefone        |  
| email           |
```

E agora criar um trigger `BEFORE UPDATE` na tabela contato, assim:

```
CREATE TRIGGER contato_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE
   ON contato FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO contato_hist(id_contato,telefone,email)
     SELECT * FROM contato where id_contato = NEW.id_contato;

END
```

Desse forma, antes que aconteça um update na tabela `CONTATO` vai rodar o código da sua trigger, que esta inserindo na tabela `CONTATO_HIST` tudo que tem na tabela `CONTATO` com o mesmo `id_contato` que você esta fazendo o update (`NEW.id_contato`).   Se quiser pode adicionar mais campos na sua tabela `CONTATO_HIST` e gravar o usuário que fez o update, a data, hora, o que você quiser.
Dessa forma esse histórico fica transparente para sua aplicação, não precisa mudar nada no PHP.

Coloquei um exemplo no [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6ad8ce)

Comment: Depois de 1 ano, acredite, isso solucionou o problema hoje. Acabou que não seguimos com essa ideia, mas o cliente acabou voltando nessa tecla hoje, e de lá para cá me familiarizei bem com os `TRIGGER` o que vai facilitar muito essa implementação. Obrigado.